# Can I use a conditional type on a function to indicate a return value of boolean or an object implementing an interface

Tags: typescript

I'm trying something like this...

```
export class LinkInterface {
  rel: string
  href: string
  method: string
}
```

And then in a function

```
export function getLinkInterfaceForRel(links: LinkInterface[], targetRel: string): boolean | LinkInterface {
  if (links.length < 1) return false;

  const returnLink: LinkInterface[] = links.filter(el => el.rel.toLowerCase() === targetRel.toLowerCase());

  return returnLink.length > 0 ? returnLink[0] : false;

}
```

I use the function like this:

```
const getStatisticsLinks = getLinkInterfaceForRel(this.question.links, 'Get_Statistics');
if (getStatisticsLinks) {
 // This line is where the "property href does not exist" error happens during compile
 this.service.get(getStatisticsLinks.href).subscribe(.....);
}
```

However, on compile I'm getting the error: `Property 'href' does not exist on type 'boolean | LinkInterface'`

I also tried something like this:

```
type LinkInterfaceOrBoolean = boolean | LinkInterface;

export function getLinkInterfaceForRel(links: LinkInterface[], targetRel: string): LinkInterfaceOrBoolean {}
```

But I get a similar error (href doesn't exist on type LinkInterfaceOrBoolean).

I *think* I'm supposed to be using conditional types here but having difficulty wrapping my head around what seems like a simple thing - what should I be doing?

Comment: What's the condition for the function to return a boolean instead of a LinkInterface ?

Comment: Does that error appear in the code here?  Please consider editing the code to constitute a [mcve] that demonstrates your problem as described in [ask] so that you can get a relevant answer that addresses your issue.

Comment: you'll probably need to write a typeguard for `LinkInterface`

Comment: Updated to add more code

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you want to test `if(getStatisticsLinks) { ... }` and narrow the type to `LinkInterface` when test passes, this is actually very easy. Your function never returns `true`, only `false`, so the return type can be `LinkInterface | false` instead of `LinkInterface | boolean`.

That said, I would suggest returning `undefined` rather than `false` here, since that's a more usual way to indicate the absence of a result. The `if` condition still works in the same way, since `undefined` is falsey. It also simplifies the implementation:

```js
function getLinkInterfaceForRel(links: LinkInterface[], targetRel: string): LinkInterface | undefined {
    targetRel = targetRel.toLowerCase();
    // could also use .find(...) here, which returns undefined if no match is found
    return links.filter(el => el.rel.toLowerCase() === targetRel)[0];
}
```

[Playground Link](http://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgDKgNYElzXk5AbwFgAoZC5KCAGwC5kBnMKUAczMuQAtqYHmrEB3KUAthDDcA9gBMBLdmQC+ZMjACuIBGGDSQyNpPQhsuWIggAxaVABKtABQ1MjBibOQLSANoBdABpkMDgoIzAHeiZFYQBKd0wcL3wUAB9kLVkIGFAIWSJOSmowDSgDF1NGADockFlHWmQAXgA+ZFoq6hoqsGlUaQB3aABhOEYIR1jmpqbg0PDInr7BkbGJ2NiAbhU1UhpJZFCoBNMkvEt-ZuQfQopCKloGAHIYaWknoN5s54AjUI-kBIpHJfnAAF5PZDKAJkPzbUhkBD6ZiGSQAZRCumYwAQjA8jCu4Q8Z281lskUcRyCTwA4pIAPoYuBY3S4p5bMjAGDIRzhJksnF41xTEiiCgAenFwQAngAHFDAAnE8wpW7IJEgRjSfZVGjSNi89GYxWsoWVDmkVSkIA)

Comment: Thanks - this is something I've wrestled with with in Typescript before. I think my solution was to cast the type within the condition since I know it must be of the expected type for it to have passed the condition. This is much cleaner though.

Answer (score 0):

You will need to write your own typeguard to "narrow down" the type, such that the TypeScript compiler knows that `getStatisticsLinks` is of type `LinkInterface` when it is being used in  `this.service.get(getStatisticsLinks.href).subscribe(.....);`.

This is one way you can write the type guard:

```
function isLinkInterface(obj: LinkInterface | boolean): pet is LinkInterface {
  return (obj as LinkInterface).href !== undefined;
}
```

And then, this is how you can use it:

```
const getStatisticsLinks = getLinkInterfaceForRel(this.question.links, 'Get_Statistics');

if (getStatisticsLinks && isLinkInterface(getStatisticsLinks)) {    
  this.service.get(getStatisticsLinks.href).subscribe(..);
}
```

The `isLinkInterface()` type guard will return `true` only if `getStatisticsLinks` is of type `LinkInterface` (because it has the href property), and then `this.service.get()` will be called conditionally.